# Exporting to Excel from SQL Server getting error

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

I have this script that's works fine

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess' , 1 
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
RECONFIGURE


INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;hdr=yes;Database=C:\aa\Customer.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Hoja1$]')
select  a.Email from AspNetUsers a
```

This works fine and get a column in my existing Customer.xlsx spreadsheet but when I try to select several columns from the table

```
select  a.Email, a.Id from AspNetUsers a
```

I get the folowing error

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

I've tried everything but I can't figured out why this happening.

My idea is to export to excel an entire resultset using some like this.

```
Select * from AspNetUSers
```

And I get the same error.

I've been searching for hours I don't found something good to understand this.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and 2008 In both get the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just open the Excel
2. Give column name on each columns in first Row of Sheet1
3. save the Excel
4. execute the script again.. It'll work!

references [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/11212/shows-error-in-creating-excel-sheet-from-sql)